# Device Orientation Changed notification event not called in other controllers other than main view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

In my application i have 3 view controllers each is navigating by a button click. In my first view controller i have added the command

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(Orientchanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

it works only on my first `UIViewController` which is added in `appdelegate`. But it donot work for other `UIViewControllers` and call the `selector` event. What is the reason? Should I add other `view controllers` to appdelagate.

---

An example of the code in the `Orientchanged:` method:

```
- (void)Orientchanged:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    UIDeviceOrientation devOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    scrollWidth_L = 1024;
    scrollWidth_P = 768;
}
```

Comment: I have used presentviewcontroller for navigation

Comment: Yes i have added addobserver command in viewDidLoad of each controller. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes when i click a button in one UIViewcontroller it navigate to another and should check the orientation on loading to get some values declared in the notification changed event selector.  - (void)Orientchanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation devOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    
    scrollWidth_L = 1024;
    scrollWidth_P = 768;
    
} like this code i need to do for other controllers.

Comment: I'm not following you, but if you want the standard notifications, no `addObserver` is needed. If you need your own notification method called (for reasons that you have not yet made clear), then you need an `addObserver` for each controller. And I wouldn't generally have hardcoded scroll with values, but rather I'd be grabbing the `self.view.bounds.size.width`, which adjusts size accordingly. Maybe you should update your question with more complete code samples of (a) all rotation related methods; and (b) if you're using this `scrollWidth_L` elsewhere, give us a snippet of that, too.

Comment: Why can you not do your code in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`, which requires no `addObserver`?

Comment: That addObserver call will only cause the Orientchanged method to be called for the specific object instance that `self` (the addObserver: parm) addresses at the time that addObserver is invoked.  Any other instance of that class or any other class will not have it's similarly-named method invoked as a result of that one function call.

Answer (score 3):

Add these methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    UIInterfaceOrientation devOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    CGFloat scrollWidth_L = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat scrollWidth_P = self.view.bounds.size.height;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == devOrientation || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == devOrientation) {
        // Code for landscape setup

    } else {
        // Code for portrait setup

    }
}
```

Comment: This is UI orientation, not device orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You have added an observer for the specific `viewController`. You will have to add in all other `viewController`s for knowing  the current visible `viewController` orientation changed.

If you want to know globally then add observer in `appDelegate`.

**Note** : Don't forget to remove `observer` when not needed.

**EDIT** : Observer depends on where it contains. Here in your case `addObserver:self` , `self` is your first view controller.

Comment: Can't understand can you explain a bit more. I added in all the controllers but it not works

Comment: Perhaps you should look into override your view controller's orientation did change methods instead of listening for global device orientation changed messages. (Make sure you override `-supportedDeviceOrientations` in your view controller subclass.)